# What is the proper remote shutter release for Canon 5D Mark iii?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, remote, shutter-release, canon-5d-mark-iii

I got lost finding the right remote shutter release for my Canon 5D Mark iii. I have  the [Hänhel Combi](http://www.hahnel.ie/index.cfm?page=dslrremotecontrols&id=64&pId=64) for Canon, which I use to use with Canon 550D but seems no use with 5D Mark iii.

I googled and found a lot of different products but I don't want to buy a wrong one.

My budget is about 20£ for a normal cable release or about 60£ for a wireless one. I know there is one from Canon about 300£, but it's too expensive for me to spend on a shutter release. For wireless, infrared is not an option for me.

Comment: Get the one from ebay for a few bucks. They work flawlessly. They're radio triggers which is actually better than the line-of-sight ones from Canon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canon makes 2 remotes, the timer model and the non-timer model.

The non-timer model, the [RS-80N3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009R6VZ) is the cheaper one. I don't own one of these. The timer model, the [TC80N3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00009XVA3) is actually a pretty useful device. I was using it, well planning to use to shoot the Leonids, just the other day. I've had mine for about 4 years and I seem to use it at least several times a year.

Comment: Now I understand it's N3 type remote .. that made me confusued as I have a lot of cable release and non of them fit on 5DIII so .. Thanks ..

Answer (score 2):

[Pixel Oppilas wireless](http://pixelhk.com/Proshow.aspx?id=300) remote shutter release works in radiowaves up to 300 ft (100 m) distance. I have one for my Sony and I'm quite happy with it, though the shutter release button on the remote unit could be a bit stiffer. Though mine is already old, they may have changed the design by now. My experience is that it is reliable, cheap and it works also in freezing weather without issues, but I haven't taken it (yet) to real Finnish winter temperatures where battery life is seriously shortened. I'll do that later this winter.

[image: my own Pixel remote]

Price of this wireless remote is currently $25 in Amazon, so it's well within your budget. Choose the version with N3 connector for your Canon 5D mark III.

Answer (score 0):

The EOS 5D Mark III uses the *N3* connector. Most Canon pro cameras use this connector as well. Any remote from Canon or a third party with an *N3* connector should work with your 5D Mark III.

[image: N3]

Canon consumer cameras, such as your 550D, use the *E3* connector that is basically the same as the end of a 2.5mm stereo headphone cable.

[image: E3]

In either case the wired remotes are relatively simple electrical switches. The only difference is the shape of the connectors. This is also true for a [wide variety of cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/46880/15871) with wired release ports.