# Tr-90 remote release

Tags: remote, canon-70d

So I went in to buy a remote release for my canon 70D. I didn't have it with me, but they said that the phottix TR-90 c8 is the right one for the 70d... ha but as far as I know, that connector is definitely not going to fit in my remote release hole on the 70d. I'm going to take it back tomorrow (but everywhere it's saying that I use a c8)
Haha. So if anyone knows if I should use a c6 or a c8, that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/47443/15871 for the difference between the Canon N3 and E3 connectors. Phottix calls the N3 the c8 and the E3 the c6 in their product lines, but that is not the way Canon designates them.

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/46877/15871 regarding the way most remote release terminals are wired in DSLRs. The only difference between the vast majority of them is the shape of the connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the C6.  Basically look for shutter releases that are compatible with the Canon XXXD models.

The connector for the shutter release port on the 70D is the same as for the dRebels: a 2.5mm stereo miniplug, not the three-pin proprietary connector port used on the 50D and previous XXD models--that's probably where the confusion is coming in.  With the move of the 60D downtier, the XXD line became more similar to the dRebels--using SD cards, rather than CF, and using the 2.5mm minijack shutter release connector, rather than the "N3" connector.

Comment: You're welcome. Even if I am female. :)

Comment: Ha ya... sorry, I thought about that probably like 5 minutes after I sent sent that....

Comment: No worries! It's the interwebz. These things happen. ;)