# Is it possible to do time lapse photography with a Canon 70D without using a laptop?

Tags: canon, timelapse, canon-70d

Canon 70D has options of using remote shutter and using apps with iPhone/Android devices. Is there any option to do timelapse photography using either of the above where I can click photos at a specified interval? I know this can be done using the Canon EOS application provided. Is there any other possible way of doing this?

Comment: Although this question addresses a wider number of cameras than only the 7D, the question and answers are all applicable to the 7D.   http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/53065/15871

Answer (score 7):

If you're asking how to take the images for a timelapse, what you're looking for is an **intervalometer**.  And yes, there are several ways of achieving this, aside from a smartphone/tablet and the Canon EOS app.  There are several smartphone apps that can do this.  There are hardware intervalometers built into cable shutter releases. There are dedicated (mostly Arduino-based) devices, and there is the [Magic Lantern](http://www.magiclantern.fm) firmware add-on (which, at the time of writing is not compatible with the 70D and [only in early development](http://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=8419.175)).

If you're asking is there a way to combine the individual frames into a video file format without using a computer, I think the answer is no.  The 70D does not have the capability of creating a video clip from time-lapse frames