# Is there an external intervalometer for Pentax cameras?

Tags: timelapse, pentax, accessories

I would like to take HDR time lapse photos on my Pentax K-50. That means I want to take a set of three bracketed exposures, then another three exposures 10 seconds later, and so on.

As far as I can tell there is no way to do this using the camera's built-in "interval shooting" feature, because if I activate both exposure bracketing and interval shooting, the exposure bracketing setting is ignored.

However, what I can do is set the camera up so that a single press of the shutter release takes three bracketed exposures. So if there is an external device that can trigger the shutter at timed intervals then, hopefully, that means I can take bracketed exposures at regular intervals.

However, I haven't been able to find such a device for sale online. I can find infrared and cable-based shutter releases for Pentax cameras, but I haven't found one with a built-in interval timer. Does such a device exist, and if so what is its name / model number? Or is there another way in which one can take HDR time lapses on the K-50?

Comment: It seems from some sites that cable shutter releases are a universal system, i.e. not specific to a particular make of camera. If that's the case then I can just buy any one. (Maybe I should ask that as a separate question.)

Comment: Typing "intervalometer for pentax" into Amazon comes up with dozens of products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just one of many similar products available that fit Pentax cameras or any other camera with a 2.5mm stereo micro-plug.

[https://www.amazon.com/Neewer-Shutter-Release-Remote-Control/dp/B003Q9RERY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003Q9RERY)

[image]

For more, please see: [Is there a good remote timer compatible with most Nikon and Canon (and Pentax and Sony) cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46877/is-there-a-good-remote-timer-compatible-with-most-nikon-and-canon-cameras/46880#46880)

Comment: If the K-50 has the same style socket as the K-10D, yes, that one will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Phottox TR-90 on my Pentax cameras for such purposes. It can be programmed to invoke the shutter via a cable connection with either a programmable delay or a long time exposure.

Answer (score 0):

I've been successfully using timelapse gear from Dynamic Perception for several years with my K100D and K7 Pentax cameras.  DP's controllers (which are intervalometers, among many other features such as movement control along a dolly, should you desire) plug into the camera's 3/32" remote control receptacle via a wire (I believe the K50 has such an input receptacle). Great fun!