# Is there a mobile app that can simulate the Canon bluetooth remote?

Tags: canon, remote

On newer Canon cameras (such as the 200D that I own) there is no longer the option to use the IR remote. Instead you have to buy a special Bluetooth remote (the [Canon BR-E1](https://shop.usa.canon.com/shop/en/catalog/wireless-remote-control-br-e1)) that costs $50 and is quite bulky.

Is it possible to replace it with a mobile app somehow? I know there's an [official app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.canon.ic.cameraconnect&hl=en) to control the camera through Live View, but it's quite slow and only works in Wi-Fi mode.

Comment: Canon's web page suggests their app works on Bluetooth as well as WiFi https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/explore/solutions-services/mobile-apps/camera-connect

Comment: @user1068122 it does "work", but you can't control the shutter in Bluetooth mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest version of Camera Connect App have a "Bluetooth remote controller" function, doing the same as BR-E1. It doesn't support all cameras - i.e. it doesn't work for Canon 77D, but does work for the R8.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just because there is no IR port does not mean the camera can not be remotely controlled other than by Bluetooth. The camera also has the more traditional port for a wired remote.

In the case of the 200D the wired shutter release port is a 2.5mm mini stereo jack which allows a simple three way switch (off/half press/full press) to operate the camera's shutter remotely.

Since wired remotes are [incredibly simple and almost universal](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/46880/15871) in the way they operate (the only difference between those made for the vast majority of different cameras are the shape of the connectors), there are a plethora of accessories available to use the wired remote port as a wireless radio trigger.

If you're close enough to use a wired connection, many remotes are both very affordable and fairly compact. [This one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MN657GG) is currently $8 USD at amazon.com:

[image]

If you want a greater range than a wired cable allows, there are radio triggers that use the wired shutter release port to interface with the camera. [This one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B072JSMTY9) operates in the 2.4GHz band and has a range of approximately 80 meters. It's also fairly compact and affordable.

[image]

If you're really dedicated to using WiFi there's always [DIY on the cheap](https://hackaday.com/2016/01/24/five-bucks-three-parts-wifi-camera-remote/).