# D750 back button focus and remote

Tags: nikon, remote, back-focus, nikon-d750

I have a Nikon D750 on which I have setup focusing to be on the AE-L/AF-L button (not on the standard shutter release button). Works fine. Now when using a remote (in my case the Pluto trigger), leaving the camera and lens on AF, I am unable to focus. The Pluto trigger app even has a dedicated "Focus" shutter release mode that is supposed to focus, then shoot, but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pluto trigger sends the "Focus" command as a *shutter button half press* command, rather than a command to "Focus." This is because the connection of the receiver to the camera is via the camera's wired remote port.

That's also what wired remote release cables do. The commands sent by the remote are actually commands for "Shutter button half press" and "Shutter button full press" rather than commands for "Focus" and "Release shutter."

Comment: I found no other way to do that except to switch my camera back to "normal" focusing mode and then obviously it works. Thanks for your confirmation. I understand that now.

Comment: Yeah, the wired shutter release ports are pretty basic open/shut switches wired in parallel to the shutter button, and not connected in any way to the camera's logic. It's basically just an extension cord for the shutter button itself.

Comment: For more on how the vast majority of wired shutter releases work, please see [Is there a good remote timer compatible with most Nikon and Canon (and Pentax and Sony) cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/46877/15871)

Comment: Good info, thanks. I find the Pluto trigger to be a great little tool btw. It's very versatile with one downside being that you need your smartphone... But in a way I find it cool too as you (or at least I) rarely go anywhere without my smartphone. The Pluto batteries last very very long and you should only be limited by your smartphone battery for a long night of shooting... No sync issues, never, and many useful features.

Comment: As long as you are close enough to the camera that a wired release would suffice in terms of distance, what advantages does the Pluto app offer over a wired release with a built-in intervalometer?

Comment: Well I would suggest you check the [features list](https://plutotrigger.com/pages/features). It's a clever little thing. It detects sound, light, you can do timelapse, startrails and more. It can use its own sensors or those of your smartphone depending the mode you're using. All that is controlled via a smartphone app, so it's clear and intuitive to use. Btw. I am not related to these guys at all. Just a satisfied customer ;)

Comment: But there are devices that do all of those things without running down my phone's battery.