# Can i use intervalometer to engage continuous shooting?

Tags: sony-alpha, intervalometer, continuous-drive

Can i use intervalometer to engage continuous shooting (setting continuous with speed ~5fps on camera instead of bulb) for 20 seconds and delay/timer of few minutes ?
(with sony a6000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can i use intervalometer to engage continuous shooting (setting continuous with speed ~5fps on camera instead of bulb) for 20 seconds and delay/timer of few minutes ? (with sony a6000)

Yes, you can (assuming you mean an external intervalometer hooked to the camera's wired cable release port). When the cable release completes the "full press" circuit via the camera's cable release port, it has the *exact same effect* as pressing the camera's actual shutter button fully (other than the camera motion that might be introduced by touching the camera).

If the camera is set to 'Bulb' the shutter will stay open for the length the cable release maintains the completed "Full Press" circuit.

If the camera is set to a specific shutter speed (more accurately called a shutter time or time value), then when the "full press" circuit is completed by the cable release the camera will fire the shutter for the set shutter time.

**If the cable release maintains the "full press" circuit for several seconds continuously the same thing will happen as if you pressed the camera's shutter button for the same number of seconds.**

If the camera is set to "single shot" one photo would be taken.

If the camera were set to "continuous shooting" as many shots as would be taken while holding down the camera's shutter button for the same number of seconds would be taken when the cable release maintains the "full press" circuit.

For more on just how simple and near universal, other than the shape of the connector, the connections between cameras and wired cable releases (with or without intervalometers) are please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/46880/15871) to [Is there a good remote timer compatible with most Nikon and Canon (and Pentax and Sony) cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/46877/15871)

Comment: well... that's the theory and i understand that (that's what i think), i just don't know why everyone says 'camera HAS to be in bulb, because there is a conflict etc', and i don't know if there is any other limitation...

Comment: @razor Are you using an external intervalometer or one that is built-in to the camera?

Comment: i've bought cheap intervalometer (Shoot) and it works like i want. (it  sends long press signal and engage continuous shooting)

Answer (score 0):

No, Interval timer has to be Bulb.  Otherwise, you will have two factors both trying to work the shutter, a conflict which cannot work right.

You could use a regular remote shutter release (cable or radio) to active the several minutes continuous burst (without an interval timer). Those with a cable have a slide switch to hold the button down itself, until you slide it back.

Or of course, that is what interval timers do, regularly trigger Bulb shutter of specified duration every interval.  Interval timers in some more recent cameras have a setting to take N pictures every interval (interval has to be that much longer).

The interval has to be at least slightly longer than the shutter duration. If any such conflict, timer will simply skip those in conflict, ragged performance.

If this use is for stars and you want an exposure of 30 seconds, you must realize that the cameras 30 second exposure is actually 32 seconds. 30 is just a nominal marking, the precise time is 32 seconds.  This is required so the that the 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 progression is each exactly 2x time, and the camera knows to do it right.  So a 33 second interval will be necessary for a "30" second exposure.  If any doubts, simply just time your 30 second shutter to verify. And you can test your attempt first, before going out into the field.

Comment: is there any limitation that says i need to set BULB on camera and not anything else ?

Comment: what conflict? i want to set continuous drive on camera and set shutter time =20sec on intervalometer, it should force continuous shooting for 20 seconds, right ? (are there any other limitations i'm not aware of?) and all that with initial delay of 3 minutes (or two, or five - to configure)

Comment: Sorry, it probably depends on WHICH interval timer you use. The interval timer in the camera if any cannot use Bulb, but uses the shutter speed you set. I assumed an external interval timer, which sets both interval and shutter speed, and for any external agent to control shutter speed, the camera has to be Bub, so they can.  Except I doubt Continuous shutter can work with Bulb .It would not know when to stop and repeat.  A very simple test will tell you if that is the case. Try it, then you'll know. I'm thinking there is no case when continuous shutter works with any timer.

Comment: "I'm thinking there is no case when continuous shutter works with any timer." A simple test would prove such thinking to be totally incorrect.

Comment: So what case would that be (if you know)?  I assume you can only mention the self timer, which I totally reject as trivial, not having any effect on the exposure time.

Comment: i wouldn't ask if i can try, cause i don't have intervalometer (and i don't know if i have a use for such one).

i want to use external intervalometer, set initial delay for, let's say 3 mins,  and then shutter press for 20 sec (can intervalometer simulate 20 sec long shutter press?), and while my camera is in continuous drive mode, it'll take 100 pictures (5fps and 20 sec, in theory, don't worry about buffer or sd card)

Comment: i've bought cheap intervalometer (Shoot) and it works like i want. (it sends long press signal and engage continuous shooting)

Answer (score 0):

I've bought cheap wired intervalometer (Shoot) and it works like i want.

It sends long press signal (for 2 seconds for example) and engage continuous shooting (if continuous drive is set in camera).

so i can get 20 images, 5fps for 2 secs (set on intervalometer) and initial delay of 3 mins (set on intervalometer)

Comment: How does this answer materially differ from [this already existing one](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/93716/15871)?

Comment: well, it's just a confirmation of theory.
before that, no one was able to confirm, everything was just a speculations...

Comment: The other answer is pretty clear that IF you meet the conditions outlined THEN you WILL get the desired results. The only place *theory* is mentioned is in your first comment to it. The first three words following a quote from the question say, "Yes, you can." I don't know how one can be any clearer than that.

Comment: i thought you were reasoning (theory), not testing this in practice.
ok, i'll accept your answer if it please you :)