# Taking picture every x seconds

Tags: astrophotography, sony-alpha, stars, intervalometer

I would like to make star trails picture and I saw that one good way to do so is to take picture every like 30 seconds and them stack them all.

I have Sony a6500 camera. Is there a way to set this in camera as a setting or do I have to buy some hardware to do it?

If so, what is the name of such a device?

Thank you!

Comment: Existing questions here with the [*intervalometer* tag](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intervalometer) have a lot of information that explains how to do this.

Comment: You might want to start with [Can i use intervalometer to engage continuous shooting?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/93697/15871) and [How can timelapse sequences be shot without in-camera support?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/713/15871) and [Is there a good remote timer compatible with most Nikon and Canon (and Pentax and Sony) cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/46877/15871)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install on camera PlayMemories application named Time-lapse. Here is [link to UK site](https://www.playmemoriescameraapps.com/portal/usbdetail.php?eid=IS9104-NPIA09014_00-000003).

Or you can use remote shutter like [this](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B019XR27U6/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o07_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

If you tether your camera you can use software like Capture One to shoot time-lapse sequences.

NB! No affiliation with any of the above companies.

Comment: I saw this app but it auto combines the images into a video no? I just want to make a bunch of stills that I will combine by myself later in Ps or Lr.

Comment: As far as I know no, will not combine the images. So you will be free to use any other product to do this. From the page: "You can choose to save the still images as a series of photos instead of a movie."

Comment: I guess I missed it. Thank you mate!

Comment: One more question. Do you know if this app allows me make this interval with locked aperature/iso/shutter speed? or it takes control over the every picture?

Comment: @Ben, no idea, I had A6000 but do not succeed to install this module (country limitations)