# What is the configuration for a D70s / MC-DC1 connector?

Tags: nikon, remote, nikon-d70

I have an old D70s, and I'd like to trigger it using the wired remote shutter port from a computerized device like a Sabre (which doesn't provide an adapter for this camera) or an Arduino. The connector type is a `MC-DC1`. It's used with a four wire remote, but Nikon doesn't provide any technical specifications.

I imagine that, since there is no power source in the trigger, it's as simple as shorting two wires together to trigger a shutter release. But what are the other two wires for? I also want to see if anyone has any experience with this before shorting wires together in case there is any possibility of damage.

Comment: I don't know that actual answer, however a cheap 3rd party wired remote actually uses 3 wires (they can use regular audio TRS 3.5mm plugs & cables as extensions); by extrapolation - ground, half-squeeze, shutter release. As they require no power (unless you want the timer functions in the remote), I would agree with your guess that they are simply shorted. [Example on Amazon with multi-connectors](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Neewer®-Shutter-Release-MarkIII-MarkII/dp/B01FFFDX6C/ref=sr_1_21?dchild=1&keywords=nikon+wired+remote&qid=1606829988&s=electronics&sr=1-21)

Comment: Everything you ever wanted to know about remote cable release connections: http://www.doc-diy.net/photo/remote_pinout/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a good remote timer compatible with most Nikon and Canon (and Pentax and Sony) cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46877/is-there-a-good-remote-timer-compatible-with-most-nikon-and-canon-and-pentax-an)

Comment: @MichaelC, no but Steven did below. I've accepted his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pin 1 is unused. Pin 2 connects to ground to activate the shutter. Pin 3 connects to ground to activate autofocus. Pin 4 is ground.

[image]