# Using bulb mode with EOS Remote app without having to hold down shutter button possible?

Tags: canon, remote, apps, bulb-mode

Does the EOS Remote app somehow support timed shutter speeds (for their DSLRs) longer than 30 seconds or a press-and-lock feature when in `BULB` mode? I've not found such a feature and I guess it could be absent so the (free) app won't compete with Canon's own expensive shutter releases.

As of now I need to keep pressing the button, and it would ruin the image if I have to press a lit display during the entire exposure. It's both very cumbersome and the light from the display affects the final image.

Comment: How does pressing the lit display of your control device ruin the image? Can you not shield the camera from the light of the control device?

Comment: @MichaelClark I sometimes step into the picture to use my high powered spotlight to paint my subject matter that would otherwise be underexposed compared to the sky. If I'm walking around with an illuminated phone my picture would be filled with light traces.

Comment: A wired cable release that allows you to lock the shutter button open would probably be your best solution. They are fairly cheap. Just because you *can* control your camera with a phone doesn't mean it is the best method to control your camera when you have easy access to the actual controls on the camera.

Comment: @MichaelClark i agree that cable release is better suited and I use them when I do planned long exposures. But if it's possible with an app it would let me do long exposures even I've left the cable release at home.

Comment: Wireless remote shutter does not have to be expensive. See my answer to ["What is the proper remote shutter release for Canon 5D mark III?"](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29901/what-is-the-proper-remote-shutter-release-for-canon-5d-mark-iii/47453#47453) but notice the connector for your Canon might be different. They have them all covered and is even cheaper than Canon's wired remote.

Comment: Have you considered using the [CHDK firmware](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK)? You can write a [UBASIC](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/UBASIC) script for this, and I think others already did that.

Comment: What camera model are we talking about? Powershot? EOS-mount dSLR?

Comment: @inkista it's about DSLRs, I've clarified that now.

Comment: As I said below, get several of the $15 Ebay specials and you won't have to worry about forgetting one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the EOS Remote app does not have a press-and-lock feature for bulb-mode shooting, like, say, the Triggertrap app does.  However, the Triggertrap app is unlikely to work for you, either, given that you need two smartphones to use the wi-fi feature for triggering, as well as a camera shutter cable and dongle.

Your best bet is, as has been mentioned, to try a different form of shutter release--either remotes or a cable release that do have a lock. Magic Lantern's Bulb Timer feature or a CHDK script may work for you to do this without additional hardware, but this depends on whether or not there's a suitable build for your specific camera.

Answer (score 2):

Any wired remotes that are compatible with canon cameras will work. Look for one that can lock. I found mine new for less than $15.

If you don't want to spend the money, look for an old wired cell phone headset with a 2.5mm stereo jack. cut the wire as far from the jack as possible and strip the end of the wire.
Most headphone wires have three wires, each with a very thin colored coating. Carefully scrape off the coating, plug in the jack, and individually touch two of the wires together. try different combinations until the shutter releases and unplug the cable. Twist the wires together and wrap the end with tape.
Don't worry about possibly damaging the camera. I've done this a number of times, and years later, I haven't had any issues.

Comment: Sorry but this does not answer the question. The question is not about using a regular shutter release, but rather the official EOS Remote app.

Comment: I disagree- it answers the question in that it offers a perfectly reasonable solution to the problem. Worried about leaving it at home? Get several of the $15 Ebay specials. I've had no problem with mine since I got it 10 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the bulb mode you just need to press the shutter button once on your phone in the **camera connect** app and it starts the timer and you press the shutter button again in the app to release it. Remember it is Camera connect **not EOS remote**. The latter is kind of obsolete